# Extract the start and end position of a common identifier

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, bioinformatics

I have a file that looks like this:

```
Id       Chr     Start   End  
Prom_1   chr1    3978952 3978953  
Prom_1   chr1    3979165 3979166  
Prom_1   chr1    3979192 3979193  
Prom_2   chr1    4379047 4379048  
Prom_2   chr1    4379091 4379092  
Prom_2   chr1    4379345 4379346  
Prom_2   chr1    4379621 4379622  
Prom_3   chr1    5184469 5184470  
Prom_3   chr1    5184495 5184496
```

what I would like to extract is the start and end of the same `Id` like this:

```
Id       Chr     Start   End  
Prom_1   chr1    3978952 3979193  
Prom_2   chr1    4379047 4379622  
Prom_3   chr1    5184469 5184496
```

as you have noticed the number of repeated `Id` is not constant between the start and the end. Any idea would be very appreciated.

Comment: Are all coordinates on the positive strand, or are some start coordinates greater than the end coordinate?

Comment: all the start coordinates are grater than the end yes, also the library was un-stranded so there is not need of strand information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With GNU [datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/):

```
datamash -H -W -g 1,2 min 3 max 4 <input
```

Comment: could you please explain a bit?

Comment: GNU `datamash` has a [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/manual/datamash.html), it's pretty straightforward from there.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with a classic loop to read the file or with other ways like awk , but i'm not good in awk to give you a solution based on awk. Bellow solution works ok in bash and use simple awk , grep and arrays.

With a known id (by parameter or by user input)

```
id="Prom_1" #Or for user input read -p "Give Id :" id
header=$(head -1 a.txt) #get the 1st line and store it as header.
data=($(grep $id a.txt)) #grep the file for given the id and fill an array
echo "$header"
echo -e "${data[0]}\t${data[1]}\t${data[2]}\t${data[-1]}" #data[-1] refers to the last element of the data array
#Output:
Id       Chr     Start   End  
Prom_1  chr1    3978952 3979193
```

The trick is that the array gets all the grep values separated by white space (default IFS) and thus the array looks like this :

```
root@debi64:# id="Prom_1";data=($(grep $id a.txt));declare -p data
declare -a data=([0]="Prom_1" [1]="chr1" [2]="3978952" [3]="3978953" [4]=$'\nProm_1' [5]="chr1" [6]="3979165" [7]="3979166" [8]=$'\nProm_1' [9]="chr1" [10]="3979192" [11]="3979193")
#declare -p command just prints out all the data of the array (keys and values)
```

To automatically scan the file for ids , you can use the uniq prog like this:

```
readarray -t ids< <(awk -F" " '{print $1}' a.txt |uniq |tail -n+2) 
#For Field separator= " " print the first field (id), print them as unique fields and store them in an array.
#Here the use of readarray is better to handle data separated by new lines.
declare -p ids
#Output: declare -a ids=([0]="Prom_1" [1]="Prom_2" [2]="Prom_3")
```

Combining all together:

```
header=$(head -1 a.txt) #get the 1st line and store it as header.
readarray -t ids< <(awk -F" " '{print $1}' a.txt |uniq |tail -n+2)
echo "$header"
for id in ${ids[@]}
do
data=($(grep $id a.txt))
echo -e "${data[0]}\t${data[1]}\t${data[2]}\t${data[-1]}"
done 

#Output 
Id       Chr     Start   End  
Prom_1  chr1    3978952 3979193
Prom_2  chr1    4379047 4379622
Prom_3  chr1    5184469 5184496
```

Answer (score 2):

can you try this awk

```
$ awk 'NR==1{print; next}NR!=1{if(!($1 in Arr)){printf("\t%s\n%s\t%s\t%s",a,$1,$2,$3);Arr[$1]++}else{a=$NF}}END{printf("\t%s\n",a)}' input.txt
Id       Chr     Start   End

Prom_1  chr1    3978952 3979193
Prom_2  chr1    4379047 4379622
Prom_3  chr1    5184469 5184496
```

---

```
awk '
NR==1{print; next}
NR!=1{
if(!($1 in Arr))
{
       printf("\t%s\n%s\t%s\t%s",a,$1,$2,$3);Arr[$1]++;
}
else
{
    a=$NF
}
}
END{
printf("\t%s\n",a)
}' input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the entries for each ID are sorted numerically on the start coordinate:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

NR == 1  {
    # Deal with header (just print it and continue).
    print; 
    next;
}

$1 != id {
    # This is a new ID.
    # Display the data for the ID we've been processing so far (if any).
    if (id) {
        print id, chr, start, stop;
    }

    # Store the data for the new ID.
    id      = $1;
    chr     = $2;
    start   = $3;
}

{
    # The stop/end coordinate will be updated for each line.
    stop = $4;
}

END {
    # At the end, display the data for the last ID.
    print id, chr, start, stop;
}
```

Testing (works with GNU `awk`, BSD `awk` and `mawk`):

```
$ ./script.awk data.in
Id       Chr     Start   End
Prom_1 chr1 3978952 3979193
Prom_2 chr1 4379047 4379622
Prom_3 chr1 5184469 5184496
```

If the entries are *not* sorted, sort them:

```
$ sort -k1,1 -k3,3n -o data.in data.in
```

This may mess up the header line though. The following is an alternative that will work:

```
$ cat <( head -n 1 data.in ) <( sed '1d' data.in | sort -k1,1 -k3,3n ) >data.new
$ mv data.new data.in
```

Requires `bash` or `ksh` though...

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with awk and storing in variables:

Take the headers of the file and put them in output file:

```
row1=$(head -1 input_file)
echo $row1 | sed -e 's/ /\t/g' > output_file
```

Take the unique values of the first column:

```
col1=$(for i in $(awk 'NR>1 {print $1}' input_file | uniq); do echo $i; done)
```

Take the first occurrence of the value in second row based on every first column value:

```
col2=$(for i in $(echo "$col1"); do grep -m1 $i input_file | awk '{print $2}'; done)
```

Take the first value of third column based on every first column value:

```
col3=$(for i in $(echo "$col1"); do grep -m1 $i input_file | tail -1 | awk '{print $3}'; done)
```

Take the last value of fourth column based on every first column value:

```
col4=$(for i in $(echo "$col1"); do grep $i input_file | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}'; done)
```

Append all those values to the output file:

```
paste -d'\t' <(echo "$col1") <(echo "$col2") <(echo "$col3") <(echo "$col4") >> output_file
```